Problem with events running inside observer
In my environment i use octane, laravel (10) and horizon. I have problem with event which have the SerializeModels trait.
My observer look like that:
public function created(Post $post): void
{
    $this->saveAdditionalData($post);

    if ($post->migration_id) {
        return;
    }

    if ($post->status->state()->is(PostStatusEnum::PUBLISHED)) {
        PostChangedEvent::dispatch($post);

        RecalculatePostPricesJob::dispatch($post);

        SendPostCreatedEmailJob::dispatch($post);

        Bus::batch([
            new AddPostToElasticsearchJob($post),
        ])
            ->then(fn() => PostSavedElasticsearchEvent::dispatch($post))
            ->dispatch();
    }
}

And i get exception about not found model:

All 3 jobs have the same exception.

The AddPostToElasticsearchJob looks like that:
class AddPostToElasticsearchJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;
    use Batchable;

    public function __construct(public readonly Post $post)
    {
        $this->queue = QueueNameEnum::ELASTICSEARCH->value;
    }

Do you have idea, what can be wrong? In my opinion if observer was called, and if it's "created" function not creating, model should exist.

Could be a timing condition. Using afterCommit may help

@aynber works well, problem solved. New thing learned :)
